# How can I get a nice view with a big triangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I am trying to draw a triangle with vertices `A(-297,-209)`, `B(-5,10)`, `C(67,31)`and inscribed.
I tried

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
     \tkzDefPoint(-297,-209){A}
     \tkzDefPoint(-5,10){B}
     \tkzDefPoint(67,31){C}
     \tkzDrawPolygon[ultra thick](A,B,C)
     \tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C)
     \tkzGetPoint{O} \tkzGetLength{rIN}         
     \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,O)
     \tkzDrawCircle[R,color=red,ultra thick](O,\rIN pt)         
     \tkzLabelPoints(B,C)
     \tkzLabelPoints(A,O)
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I get a nice view with this picture?

This is picture from *Maple*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you intend for "nice"? Enlarged? Colored? Bold?

Comment: Enlarged and bold. I tried option [ultra thick]

Comment: Some suggestions :  replace `scale=0.5` by `scale=0.05`. You can also add `line join=round` and add `[above]` in `\tkzLabelPoints[above](B,C)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to replace `ultra thick` with a specific value.  Use the `line width` key instead and set it equal to whatever dimension works for you (e.g. 10pt, 4em, 20ex, etc.).

However, I would also suggest removing the `[scale=0.5]`.  For example, in the example here, `[scale=0.5]` doesn't seem to properly scale the labels of the axes.

As mentioned, I also added the axes here with similar labeling to your image.  A few other changes added to make the labels for the points fit better.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=-300,
            xmax=50,
            xstep=50,
            ymax=50,
            ymin=-200,
            ystep=50]
    \tkzDrawX[line width=1pt,label={}]\tkzLabelX[orig=false]
    \tkzDrawY[line width=1pt,label={}]\tkzLabelY[orig=false]
     \tkzDefPoint(-297,-209){A}
     \tkzDefPoint(-5,10){B}
     \tkzDefPoint(67,31){C}
     \tkzDrawPolygon[line width=2pt](A,B,C)
     \tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C)
     \tkzGetPoint{O} \tkzGetLength{rIN}         
     \tkzDrawPoints[size=3pt](A,B,C,O)
     \tkzDrawCircle[R,color=red,line width=2pt,fill=green,fill opacity=0.3](O,\rIN pt)         
     \tkzLabelPoints[below right](A)
     \tkzLabelPoints[above left](B)
     \tkzLabelPoints[above right](C)
     \tkzLabelPoints[below right](O)
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tkz-euclide axes triangle and circle]

Comment: It would be good to change, if possible, the line join.

Comment: @Sigur I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Do you mean the circle and triangle overlapping?  Or something different?

Comment: Google for *line join cap*

Comment: It's not part of the question.  OP can create a new question if the "connection between lines in the triangle" is not to his/her liking.

Comment: Since he asked for *nice view* I think that could be useful. No problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, 'nice' is subjective and I went off the response 'enlarge and bold'.  OP can use `rounded corners` as an option for `\tkzDrawPolygon`, but it looks a bit strange with the points and heavy line.  Lightening the line by reducing the line width looks better, but the very acute angle at A doesn't round consistently with B and C.  It seems worth returning to after OP has had more time to consider line widths and other design choices that may affect it.